# How to bind JavaScript result to a div on my page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a java script file that it's output is a table with some information.
i want to show this result in one of my DIVs in my page but the result of function,placed at top of my page's Header!
What can i do to fix this?

---

this is end of my java script file ,in fact this is its output 
' document.write("")
document.write(" اوقات شرعی کلیه شهر ها   ")
document.write("")
document.write("          ")
document.write("      اذان صبح  طلوع خورشید   اذان ظهر   غروب خورشید      اذان مغرب")
document.write(" 
اوقات به افق : 
انتخاب شهراراکاردبیلارومیهاصفهاناهوازایلامبجنورد   بندرعباسبوشهربیرجندتبریزتهرانخرم آبادرشتزاهدانزنجانساریسمنانسنندجشهرکردشیرازقزوینقمکرمان  کرمانشاهگرگانمشهدهمدانیاسوجیزد   
")
document.write("") '' and this is its call at the and of my master page '

```
    $(document).ready(function ogh() {
        var CurrentDate = new Date();
        var JAT = 1;
        function pz() { };
        init(); document.getElementById("cities").selectedIndex = 12;
        coord(); main();
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#oghatSharii").append(ogh());
    });

</script>
</form>
```

'
 if you could't understand top of my code,,its output is a table

Comment: First, share your code (relevant part of it)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the HTML of the div using jquery in the ready event like follows:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
     ....
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myDiv").append(pz());
        });
        function pz() {
            // do here something useful and return the text you want to add to the div
            return "Hello there =) !!!";
        };
     </script>

 <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Don't forget to install jquery:

https://nuget.org/packages/jQuery

Comment: thanks,my function is like this,would you please do your example by this? var CurrentDate = new Date();
                            var JAT = 1;
                            function pz() { };
                            init(); document.getElementById("cities").selectedIndex = 12;
                            coord(); main();

Comment: Well you just have to define the logic in your function and return the text you want to append to your div.

Answer (score 1):

i use this

```
    function ogh()
    {
                     var CurrentDate = new Date();
                        var JAT = 1;
                        function pz() { };
                        init(); document.getElementById("cities").selectedIndex = 12;
                        coord(); main();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#oghatSharii").append(ogh());
    });
```

but i got an error : one of my functions could't access to oits data

Comment: Your ogh() function should return the text you want to append to the div, `return something`

Comment: BTW you could change `document.getElementById("cities")` to `$("#cities")`

Answer (score 0):

Some steps

1. Move your JavaScript code at the bottom of the page.
2. Make use of innerHTML (basic JavaScript) or html() (jQuery) to add so.

Comment: i do all things that you said,i moved my function at the bottom of page, and i registered my java script file on top of my page and in my ScriptManager, i use this function on my masterpage but after doing this,my function didn't work any more,before movement it worked

Comment: move at bottom of master page also

Comment: i do all things that you said,i moved my function at the bottom of page, and i registered my java script file on top of my page and in my ScriptManager, i use this function on my masterpage but after doing this,my function didn't work any more,before movement it worked

Comment: this is the code that raise error        a = new Date(CurrentDate); and this is its error message   'CurrentDate' is undefined

Comment: Please share code. I think you are missing some thing. Or if page is loading slow you have to use body on load function for basic JavaScript or ready function for jQuery. Put your code in these functions. That should work.